# Javascript: Revealing Module Pattern. Access private members

Tags: javascript, class, revealing-module-pattern

i have a javascript library exposing its members using '*Revealing Module Pattern*'. I have a particular need where i need to access its **Private Member**. Can someone help me on this regard? Any tips and tricks? I highly appreciate if someone can shed some light on this. Thanks in Advance.

[Revealing Module Pattern by Addy Osmani](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript)

```
var myRevealingModule = (function () {

    var privateVar = "Ben Cherry",
        publicVar = "Hey there!";

    function privateFunction() {
        console.log( "Name: " + privateVar );
    }

    function publicSetName( strName ) {
        privateVar = strName;
    }

    function publicGetName() {
        privateFunction();
    }


    // Reveal public pointers to
    // private functions and properties

    return {
        setName: publicSetName,
        greeting: publicVar,
        getName: publicGetName
    };

})();

myRevealingModule.setName( "Paul Kinlan" );
myRevealingModule.getName();

// is there anyway to access 'privateFunction'????
```

**Is there anyway to access '*privateFunction*'????**

Any tips and tricks? I highly appreciate if someone can shed some light on this. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You create the object of `myRevealingModule`, which contains a `setName`, a `greeting`, and a `getName`. From these, `setName` references `publicSetName` and `getName` references `publicGetName`. On its turn, `publicGetName` does exactly what you need: calls `privateFunction`.

So, to answer your question:

```
myRevealingModule.publicGetName();
```

is how you access `privateFunction`. You can even change the value of `privateVar` this way:

```
myRevealingModule.publicSetName("foobar");
myRevealingModule.publicGetName();
```

Comment: As i mentioned in the description, the class methods are exposed from a 3rd party library. Is there anyway where i can invoke `privateFunction()`? 

Something like this
`myRevealingModule.privateFunction()`

Comment: There is no way, as far as I know, unless you do a reflection, but you need a prototype for that. (http://www.htmlgoodies.com/tutorials/web_graphics/object-reflection-in-javascript.html). Why don't you like calling publicGetName?

Comment: Actually the above implementation of _myRevealingModule_ class is just an example. The actual implementation from the js library is different. Anyway thanks @Lajos Arpad.